# Prove that a prime exists such that:

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

### Notation

$$ R(\frac{b}{a}) = \text{Remainder of b divided by a} $$

### Question

Is it possible to prove where $a$ and $b$ are primes:
There always exists primes  $a$ and $b$ for all n such that $2n > b \geq n \geq a > 2$ and

$$ R(\frac{2n}{a}) = R(\frac{b}{a})$$

Comment: The remainder of $b$ divided by $a$ is written as "$b$ mod $a$". But what is $n$ here?

Comment: $n$ is an integer variable ...

Comment: Yes, OK. But is it given in advance, or are you asking whether such an $n$ exists?

Comment: It is given in advance ....

Comment: $n$ is specified in advance?  That was not clear to me.  My posted solution assumes you just wanted to find some $n$.  I'll leave it up in case it is helpful. (and perhaps you should edit the question to clarify this point).

Comment: If $a=7$ and $n=8$ then your range is $\{16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8\}$ so the only primes are $11,13$.  mod$(7)$ these are $4$ and $6$.  but $16$ is $2$ mod $7$.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question to "There always exists primes $a$ and $b$ ... "

Comment: Ok...but in that case my solution is complete.  Or do you still mean that you want this to hold for all $n$?  Your edit still does not address that point.

Comment: If you used common notation, this would just mean: "Find primes $a,b$ such that $2n\equiv b\pmod {a}$." is easy to show from a slighly stronger version of Bertand's postulate (with the added conditions you've put on $a,b$.)

Comment: @lulu It should be true for all $n$

Comment: Well, then my solution is incomplete.  But what is your exact question?  Is it "does there exist a prime $a$ such that for any $n≥a$ we can find a prime $b$ with $2n\equiv b \mod a$"?  As my example shows, this is not true for all $a$ but of course it might be true for some $a$.  Another commenter says that this is an easy extension of Bertrand's Theorem...I don't see that personally, but then I have never studied the proof of that theorem nor its extensions.

Comment: The question is for any n>2 does there exist primes $a$ and $b$ which satisfy $R(b/a) = R(2n/a) $ and $ 2<a \leq n \leq b <2n $.

Comment: Oh, that is easy then:  by Bertrand we can find a prime, call it $b$, between $n$ and $2n$.  Then $2n-b$ is odd (clearly) and, as it is less than $n$ (also clearly) it is divisible by some odd prime, call it $a$, which is less than $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  the solution below just shows that a suitable $n$ can be found.  From the comments it appears that the intent of the question was to show that any $n$ would work, in which case the solution is incomplete.

Presumably this can be done without Dirichlet, but I don't see how at the moment.

Using Dirichlet:  As $a$ is odd it is prime to $2$.  Hence there exist infinitely many primes congruent to $2$ mod$(a)$. Choose $p=ka+2$ for some sufficiently large $k$.  Then we have $$2((k-1)a+1)>p=ka+2>(k-1)a+1$$ so we can take $n=(k-1)a+1$

Note: the pigeon hole principle (together with the infinitude of primes) shows that there is some congruence class mod$(a)$ containing infinitely many primes, but (on first pass at least) it appears that you really need to show that the residue can be taken to be even.  I expect there is some way to avoid this, but in the meantime Dirichlet works fine (it just seems like overkill).

Note:  from the comments it appears that the intended question was "given an integer $n>2$, can we always find primes $a,b$ with $0<a≤n<b<2n$ such that $2n\equiv b \mod (a)$?"  That is indeed the case and it follows immediately from Bertrand's postulate.  Indeed, use Bertrand to produce a prime $b$ between $n$ and $2n$.  Then note that $2n-b$ is odd and less than $n$, hence it is divisible by some odd prime, $a<n$.  As $2n-b\equiv 0 \mod(a)$ we get $2n\equiv b \mod(a)$ and we are done.